# AWS Lambda to access internet via egress-only internet gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, aws-lambda

My lambda code simply do this but always timeout

```
exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
    const response = await fetch("https://www.google.com/");
    console.log(response); 
    return response;
};
```

I am trying to find an issue with my configuration to reach the internet.
I am trying to setup a simple connection using the egress-only internet gateway.
What am I doing wrong?

VPC:

- IPv6 CIDR (Network border group): 2406:da1c:697:400::/56 (ap-southeast-2)
- IPv4 CIDR: 10.4.0.0/16

Private Subnet

- IPv6 CIDR: 2406:da1c:697:42c::/64
- IPv4 CIDR: 10.4.48.0/20

Route table on private subnet

- 10.4.0.0/16   local
- 2406:da1c:697:400::/56    local
- ::/0  eigw-01a19162a848f3cef

ACL Inbound and Outbound

- 100  All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0   Allow
- 101  All traffic All All ::/0    Allow

Lambda security inbound

- sgr-044f95eff170f631e IPv4    Custom TCP  TCP 0   10.4.0.0/16

Lambda security group outbound

- sgr-0e26a5c8ca4cbd3b9 IPv6    All traffic All All ::/0    –
- sgr-078154ed0f052b3ba IPv4    All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0   –

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`egress-only internet gateway` is for IPv6. For lambda to access internet you need **NAT gateway** which is for IPv4. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html#vpc-internet):

> To give your function access to the internet, route outbound traffic to a **NAT gateway** in a public subnet. The NAT gateway has a public IP address and can connect to the internet through the VPC's internet gateway.

Comment: I am familiar with that approach but is there a way to make it work with egree-only internet gateway? It works well with EC2 in a private subnet why doesn't it work for lambda?

Comment: @rolele No, there is no way. You have to use NAT gateway, not gree-only internet gateway.

Comment: Here's the overview of IPv6 support for various aws services including Lambda, which says it only supports IPv6 for Public endpoints.